Dockerfile parser treating ENTRYPONT as a string rather than json
I've a dockerfile with the following entrypoint line:
ENTRYPOINT [
"java",
"-jar",
"service.jar"]

but while building the docker image it is throwing the following error-
    Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  19 |     
  20 |     ENTRYPOINT [
  21 | >>>     "java",
  22 |         "-jar",
  23 |         "service.jar"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 21: unknown instruction: "java",

But If I'm using backslashes like this, it is working perfectly fine-
ENTRYPOINT [  \
    "java", \
    "-jar", \
    "service.jar"]

I think dockerfile parser is treating it as string, rather than a json. Any idea on the fix or is there something that I'm missing?
Docker version 25.0.2

I cannot say for sure but this sounds like the intended behavior. I have a hunch that if you seperate it onto different lines the command is only seeing the first line (in this case an open bracket) which is not valid json. The backslashes are the line continue operators making all of those lines behave as if they were one line. If you want to doiuble check, try putting all of it on one line, and if you need to see it better, use word-wrap in your code editor. You should get the same result as hte solution you already found that works (using backslashes)
